# Why list comparision in python does value comparision instead of reference comparision?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have created 2 lists, one which list comprehension and other using iteration. The second list started as an empty list, so it must have a different location in memory. So, `==` should return `False`, but it returns `True`. 
Notice that the memory location is different(2nd print call):

```
my_list = [x*2 for x in range(1, 10, 1)]
new_list = []
for item in range(1, 10, 1):
    new_list.append(item * 2)

print(my_list == new_list) # True 
print(hex(id(my_list)) == hex(id(new_list))) #False
```

Please explain why this is?

Comment: Try `l1 = [1, 2, 3] l2 = [1, 2, 3] print(l1 == l2)`

Comment: That's what `==` is for: value comparison. If you want reference comparison, use the `is` operator instead.

Comment: Note that your last line can be ```print(my_list is new_list)```. ```==``` tests for equality, ```is``` tests whether the same object  is referenced.

Comment: I am new to Python. In my previous experience, == is used for reference comparision, and a custom implementation for value comparision. Thanks for the clarification everyone. Really appreciate it:-)

Answer (score 2):

Simply because those are the semantics of Python's list comparisons with the `==` operator.

If you do want reference comparison, use the `is` operator – in general, you never do want reference comparison though.

Comment: You can also find this in the official [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types)